# How far we can see in the thickest possible fog?

Tags: atmospheric-science, weather, condensation

There is quite foggy day today here, I cannot see end of the street. This made me think about how much worse can it be.

So here is my question: how thick a fog can be? What's the smallest visibility distance possible?

By visibility distance I mean how far I can see a black object against a white background in the fog.

UPDATE:

There were some nitpicks, so let me clarify a bit:

- I think of water/ice fog.
- It's said that angular size matters, so let's say an object whose angular size as big as the full moon.
- Whiteout doesn't count, assume the soil remains dark.

Comment: Is your fog restricted to $ H_2O $ ?  Just ask the Chinese how far they can see in their smog!  Another nit: there's this thing called the NIIRS scale for visibility. How big is your black object, in angular space?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think of the usual water fog. 

Does angular size matter? I think of usual landscape elements: houses, trees, pylons, etc.

Comment: Yes - rather obviously, the larger the item, the easier it is to see some sort of contrast even when badly blurred.

Comment: I am sure it can be less tham 3 meters.

Comment: Does a whiteout (snow) count?  And you're mentioning water fog, but ice fog can be much denser.

Comment: The densest fog I've seen probably had visibility of some 10 meter, but in whiteouts people can get lost in their garden.